# Manually change part of an image URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, variables, url

I am using an .aspx file along with a C#(aspx.cs) file. The goal is to enter a number in the text box and change a section of a photo's URL, so that when it's submitted it will bring up a different photo.

The .aspx code is:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">    
    <form action="demo_reqquery.asp" method="get">
    Enter Pic number: <input type="text" name="pnumber" size="20" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
 <div class="logo2">
  <asp:Image ImageUrl="http://www.website.com/pic0001.jpg" runat="server" />
 </div>
</form>
```

The user enters "pnumber" 0005 in the text box and submits. Then the 0001 in the URL is replaced with the 0005 entered bringing up photo: "http://www.website.com/pic0005.jpg"

Comment: Are you trying to do it client side or server side?

Comment: The image URLs are from a web site server.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. You said the user enters the number in the textbox and submits. Is the entire image URL the same, except for the number they enter? And are you changing the piece of it using server side code or client side? You can just split the string using substrings and JavaScript, or you can piece the image URL together inserting the numbers. Server side with C# you could use string.Format or a regex replace.

Comment: this isn't even asp.net...

Comment: @CurseStacker: if it's not ASP.NET, then what is it?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: This is classic asp. Notice the action attribute value of his form tag

Comment: No, the inner `form` submits to a classic ASP page. The current page is ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok to change the elements of your form,

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <br />
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
</div>
</form>
```

Code behind would be

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image1.ImageUrl = "http://www.website.com/pic" + TextBox1.Text + ".jpg";
}
```